# How are SOLR and Lucene related?

Tags: java, lucene, solr, search-engine

For example ZF is a bunch of code that is written in PHP and runs on Apache (assuming web server...)

SOLR is something that runs on Lucene? that is written in Java and runs on some servlet container.
What is that "something"? What is SOLR to Lucene?
What function does Lucene by itself gives me?

Comment: funny how you have the question tagged as "search-engine", and you are asking us what SOLR is!

Comment: @Raunak was not sure what is the search engine, SOLR or Lucene...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lucene is a Java library packaged as a JAR that perform the operations of information indexing and retrieval.  SOLR is a standalone full text search application that provides features like hit highlighting, and faceted search while using the underlying Lucene library as part of its internal api.

Lucene by itself give you the means through a Java API to index documents independent of file format and retrieve them, but it doesn't provide alot of the supporting functionality that a full featured web based search application requires, SOLR helps fill this gap.  Indexing and searching in SOLR is typically done through GET and POST making it easier to use as a piece of infrastructure for web apps regardless of what language they're written in.

Comment: is it a good practice to have my webapp (written in PHP) run on a different Apache then the one SOLR runs on, and query that server from inside my PHP code?

Comment: That's how I've done it, and how I've always seen it done.  I have a rails app that makes requests against a SOLR server running on a separate instance and the same for my java apps.  In your case if you hava a PHP app on Apache HTTP server, you're going to have a separate Tomcat or Jetty instance running SOLR most likely.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is a Java-based search engine.  It runs in a JVM; it does not need a web container.  It creates an index for documents as directed by a developer and uses it to perform indexed searches.

SOLR is a web app, deployed in a servlet container, that provides a web front end for doing Lucene indexed searches of collections of documents.

Comment: So, if IO have a site written in PHP and I need to show/read the results in my PHP pages, going the SOLR way is not really smart and I should go directly to Lucene? Or is there a benefit to use SOLR from php?

Comment: @ItayMoav I'd use SOLR and call it from your application. SOLR provides a nice RESTful API to do your searches. Interacting with Lucene directly from php would be more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Lucene is not a search engine on its own. It's a library to create one.

To use analogy, Lucene relates to Solr in the same way as an engine to a car. You can build different vehicles with combustion engine, but the engine on its own won't get you far.

Comment: I can do keyword driven searches using Lucene.  Index documents, then search documents.  That was true before SOLR came along.  I don't think that first statement is correct.

Comment: The most accepted [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_(computing)) of a search engine is that it's user-facing system that allows retrieval over some collection of documents. So if you write a code to execute a query, then it doesn't count yet, at least for me :)

Comment: If I'm entering keywords on a command line, and not in a browser, then I meet your definition.  That's what one could do with Lucene before SOLR.

Comment: I think that what you're talking about is the Lucene Demo, so it's already some software built on top of Lucene. I don't want to split hairs, and debate over the terminology. What I wanted to say is that if somebody isn't going to build a customized search solution and invoke Java API (as I perceived is the case with the that asker) then Solr is the way to go.